# Iterate a Set inside a List using JSTL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I need iterate a Set what is into a List using JSTL.
When I try to iterate the set, I get the following error:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "codis"

What I'm trying:

```
<c:forEach var="game" items="${games}">
    <a href="<c:url value="/product?id=${game.name}"/>"id="${game.id}">
     <c:set var="codi" value="${game.codes}"></c:set>
</c:forEach>
```

The "codes" are supposed to be the SET but i get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. Iterating over a Set or List has no difference in JSTL

```
<c:forEach var="game" items="${games}">
    <a href="<c:url value="/product?id=${game.name}"/>"id="${game.id}">
     <c:forEach var="codi" items="${game.codes}">
        <c:out value="${codi}"/> 
     </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Tag `<c:set>` is used to set value to some variable, while your case is to iterate the set and display its content.

Comment: Hello, I just tried it but i get the same error:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "codis"